# IP redirection: 2 applications, 2 servers with IP but website on one IP

Tags: apache, debian, ip

I have got three applications:

- "app_1" running on server 1 (IP1, with Apache2 on Debian 9)
- "app_2" running on server 2 (IP2, with Apache2 on Debian 9)
- "app_2_api" running on server 2 (IP2, with Apache2 on Debian 9)

I can access to app_1 like this: http://IP1.

But to access app_2 and app_2_api, I can't go on something like this: http://IP1 or http://IP1:3000/app_2_api, etc. (I can access through server 2 with IP2 and ssh). I need to go on http://IP1/app_2 and http://IP1/app_2_api.

How is this possible? I need to reproduce this but I don't know how. Any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So domain1 == IP1, domain2 == IP2, domain2_API == IP2

Make sure http://IP1 responds, and http://IP2 and http://IP2_API respond correctly.  Once you have that:

- Setup the Apache on server1, VirtualHost IP1:80 with a proxy to the IP2 site, using mod_proxy.
- Since you want to specify paths this is easy to setup a reverse proxy configuration.

  ```
  ProxyPass "/app_2" "http://IP2"
  ProxyPassReverse "/site2" "http://IP2"

  ProxyPass "/app_2_api" "http://IP2/api"
  ProxyPassReverse "/site2_api" "http://IP2/api"
  ```

Obviously this is not a complete configuration, but these would take care of the proxy part inside your VirtualHost.  One nice thing is using this configuration, your clients will never see IP2 in their address bar, so it will look as if all traffic is part of IP1 site.

Complete reference for mod_proxy:  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html

Once that is done, look into setting up domain names instead of accessing sites via the IP address...